# Interpreting QCloseEvent differently

Tags: c++, windows, qt, qwidget

I have a desktop windows application programmed in C++ with Qt. The application has several top - level windows which occasionally need to be closed and recreated programmatically. Also, when the user of the program clicks on the close button (the one next to the minimize and maximize buttons) the whole program is supposed to exit.

The problem I have is that in both cases the top level windows receive a `closeEvent()` call with a `QCloseEvent` object. I'd like to quit the program when I see that happen (because the user might have clicked the close button),  but it's also possible that the window is closing because I'm deleting it programmatically to recreate it.

Is there a way of distinguishing between these two cases in `QMainWindow::closeEvent()`?

Answer (score 4):

> Is there a way of distinguishing between these two cases in QMainWindow::closeEvent()?

Yes: the close event triggered by the user clicking on the window's close button will be a spontaneous event, the one triggered by you calling `window->close()` will not. See the documentation of `QEvent::spontaneous()` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

When you need to close your window programmatically, use `deleteLater()` instead of `close`. The window will be closed and deleted. To reopen the window you will need to create another window object.

You can also use `hide()` method. The window will be hidden but not destroyed. It can be shown again using `show()`.

In both described cases the close event does not happen and `closeEvent()` isn't called. So when `closeEvent` is called, you know that the user has pressed the close button.